# On the logarithm of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logarithms, matrix-analysis

While teaching a course on ODE, I needed to introduce the notion of matrix logarithms. I intend to define it as follows.

**Definition (Matrix Logarithm)**

Let $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.  We define

**A) Unipotent case:** When $A$ is unipotent,  i.e.  $A=I+N$, where $N\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is nilpotent, we define
$\ln A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as
$$
\ln A=\ln(I+N):=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}N^k.
$$
**B) Diagonalizable case:** When $A$ is diagonalizable,  i.e.  $A= PDP^{-1}$, where $P\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ and
$D:=\operatorname*{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ with $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$,  we define
$\ln A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as
$$
\ln A:= P\operatorname*{diag}(\ln\lambda_1,\ldots,\ln\lambda_n)P^{-1},
$$
where $\ln \lambda_i = \ln |\lambda_i|+i\arg \lambda_i$, for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.

**C) Invertible case:** When $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$,  we define
$$
\ln A:=\ln D + \ln (I+D^{-1}N), 
$$
where $D, N\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are diagonalizable and nilpotent respectively,  $A=D+N$, and $DN=ND$. The existence of $D,N$ follows from the Jordan-Chevalley Decomposition Theorem.

The problem arises when I want to prove that
$$
e^{\ln A}=A,\text{ for all }A\in GL_n(\mathbb{C}).\ \ \ \            (1)
$$

While it is easy to verify equation (1) when $A$ is unipotent or diagonalizable, I don't see any quick way to prove (1) when $A$ is a general invertible matrix. This will be easy to prove if one can show that

$$
\ln D\ln (I+D^{-1}N)=\ln (I+D^{-1}N)\ln D.\ \ \ \ \ (2) 
$$
Then, the matrix exponential laws and Equation (1) in unipotent or diagonalizable cases will settle (2) in the general case.

**QUESTION:**
Is there any easy way to prove (2), i.e.
$$
\ln D\ln (I+D^{-1}N)=\ln (I+D^{-1}N)\ln D,
$$
when $D$ is diagonalizable, $N$ is nilpotent and $DN=ND$?

Thank you.

Comment: How is $\ln(\lambda)$ defined for $\lambda\in\mathbb C^*$ without ambiguity?

Comment: @Justauser Thank you. You are right. I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried writing them both as polynomials? I.e. $\ln (I+D^{-1}N)$ is a polynomial by (A) and $\ln D= p(D)$ for a well chosen polynomial  [use e.g. a Vandermonde matrix] in accordance with your outline of (B).

Comment: This is easy to prove if $D$ and $N$ are the ones coming from Jordan theorem

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4492420/the-matrix-logarithm-is-well-defined-but-how-can-we-algebraically-see-that-i

Answer (score 0):

The question reduces to prove that $\ln(D)(D^{-1}N)^k = (D^{-1}N)^k\ln(D)$ for every $k$, so proving that $\ln(D)$, $D^{-1}$ and $N$ all commute is sufficient.

If $D=P\Sigma P^{-1}$ where $\Sigma$ is diagonal, then $$\ln(D)D^{-1}=P\ln(\Sigma)P^{-1}P\Sigma^{-1}P^{-1} \\= 
P\ln(\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}P^{-1}
\\=P\Sigma^{-1}\ln(\Sigma)P^{-1}
\\=P\Sigma^{-1}P^{-1}P\ln(\Sigma)P^{-1} =D^{-1}\ln(D).$$

Moreover, $DN=ND$ by hypothesis, so
$$\Sigma P^{-1}NP = P^{-1}NP \Sigma$$
meaning that $P^{-1}NP$ is block diagonal with blocks corresponding to the eigenspaces of $\Sigma$, that are the same as those of $\ln(\Sigma)$, so
$$\ln(\Sigma) P^{-1}NP = P^{-1}NP \ln(\Sigma)\implies \ln(D)N = N\ln(D).$$